# Geometry Nodes: How can I get the same point index from instantiated curves after they're realized?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like this to happen:

[image]

But the curves need to be realized (for some specific reason). How can I capture or store the correct value or some other method to make that happen?

[image]

Realizing the curves naturally messes things up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Resample Curve` first and specify the number of points you need there.

Then capture the *Spline Index* of the points with `Capture Attribute`, which you can use after the instantiation.

Only then use `Curve to Points` so that you can also get the rotation of the points.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Nice! This is a great answer :) 
However, 'Curve to Points' has the 'Rotation' output that I also need (sorry, it was not obvious in the question). 'Curve Tangent' doesn't yield the same great result as the 'Rotation'

Comment: @ManuJärvinen Ah, all right, then it needs to be changed just a little bit. Update is done.

Comment: YES! This was exactly what I needed to the point. Wonderful. I need this tattooed to my forehead! :) Thank you!

Comment: @ManuJärvinen You are welcome! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use *capture attribute* node to store data before realizing like this:

[image]

[image]

You can also use named attributes to read and write data:

[image]

[image]

Capture attribute may save data per point or per instance, so that you can combine these two to get index in vertical and horizontal axis (but in this case I have used mesh line, instead of Bézier, so that points are existed and data can be captured):

[image]

> it needs to be that 'Curve to Points' node

Ok. So why don't you just use modulo of curve to points count?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I tried that - let me try it again

Comment: Okay, yes, the box can be put to the topmost points, but how about the 3rd from the top for each curve, that was what I'm after here. Needs some more thinking and more nodes, I guess...?

Comment: i've updated the answer

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! Even though, I'd need that specific result that was in my first image in the question. And to make things worse, it needs to be that 'Curve to Points' node, not Resample Curve like in @quellenform 's awesome answer.

Comment: Ah, @quellenform really cracked the nut. It's exactly what I needed. Thanks to you for also contributing, of course!

Comment: i've updated the answer

Comment: Wow! Another way of solving the exact problem! Nice :) This has been a wonderful day. Thank you!